# Dim Doubles and Strings in working out percentage to insert in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a value for a range of 2 fields Men, Women to work out a percentage.

in EmployeesData.vb

```
Public Function getPercentMen() As Double

Dim result As Double

result = 0

If Men + Women > 0 Then result = (Men * 100) / (Men + Women)
        End If

Return result

End Function
```

In my Demographics.vb i have the following output:

```
Private Sub updateView()


    ' The percentage Men and Women recorded is displayed in
    ' the appropriate text boxes.

    percentMenTextBox.Text = fEmployeesData.getPercentMen().ToString()
    percentWomenTextBox.Text = fEmployeesData.getPercentWomen().ToString()

    updateView()
End Sub
```

The error i get is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Visual Studio points me to the following line

```
percentMenTextBox.Text = fEmployeesData.getPercentMen().ToString()
```

I believe that the problem is that i am trying to force a Double into a String incorrectly or something like that

I have added the entire class

```
Public Class EmployeesData
    Private fMen As Integer
    Private fWomen As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        fMen = 0
        fWomen = 0
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Men As Integer
        Get
            Return fMen
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Women As Integer
        Get
            Return fWomen
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub addMen()
        fMen = fMen + 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub addWomen()
        fWomen = fWomen + 1
    End Sub

    Public Function getPercentMen() As Double
        Dim result As Double
        result = 0
        If Men + Women > 0 Then
            result = (Men * 100) / (Men + Women)
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function getPercentWomen() As Double
        Dim result As Double
        result = 0
        If Men + Women > 0 Then
            result = (Women * 100) / (Men + Women)
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Sub reset()
        fMen = 0
        fWomen = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What values do you have for Men & Women in your class?

Comment: This probably isn't a problem with your ToString() conversion

Comment: The problem probably lies in the Men and Women properties. Please show us the code.

Comment: You can try .GetType() on your getPercentWomen() to check if the type you are trying to convert into String is a valid-convertable data type returned by your object's method...

Comment: There must be some recursion going on where your Men and Women properties are internally calling the getPercent... methods

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this error is this part:

```
Private Sub updateView()


'... snipped

    updateView()
End Sub
```

What you have here is basically a never ending loop calling a sub-routine recursively (which adds to the stack) which eventually will cause a stack-overflow.

The reason that VS points you to the `fEmployeesData.getPercentMen()` is that that call is basically the drop that makes the glass spill so-to-speak, as it performs an additional addition to the stack which at that point is full. In other words, the error message is misleading as it could just as easily have been the next call, or the next round trip calling itself.

The solution is to remove the `updateView()` call from within itself. Call it only from the outside code. If you need it to be called constantly consider using a timer instead, or use it from an event only when needed.

Your other code is fine and is not related to this error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ha!  How'd I miss that?!  Nice catch.

Comment: No problem @user1818978. If you feel it's the correct answer, please tick the answer (see below the counter).

Comment: There is something really meta about solving a StackOverflowException on StackOverflow. +1 for that!

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here. First up, I'm guessing the Men and Women variables you are using are both Integers, and so you're seeing integer division. The result of an Integer divided by an Integer is still... an Integer.

Try this instead:

```
Public Function getPercentMen() As Double

    Dim result As Double = 0.0  
    If Men + Women > 0 Then result = (Men * 100.0) / (Men + Women)   
    Return result

End Function
```

Secondly, to get a StackOverflow exception it's likely you have a self-referencing property. Check into how your Men and Women variables are implemented. If they use themselves, or if they use this getPercentMen() method, you could create a recursive call with no base case, which will result in a StackOverflow.

Comment: In VB the result of an Integer divided by an Integer is a double. And I don't see how this could produce a StackOverflowException.

Comment: Probably true, when there are no forcing to define variable data types explicitly ;) But by default the undeclared variable takes a variant type.. Anyway I like option explicit to avoid such cases.

Comment: I added the full Class, hopefully that helps you help me, as i have been pulling my hair out.  I simply just need to out put the percentage into the text box.  Based on the class data could someone recommend code that would help me write the value into textbox called percentMenTextBox.Text = fEmployeesData.getPercentMen().ToString()   or something that works to that effect. Many thanks

Comment: All cracked it,     used         percentMenTextBox.Text = CStr(fEmployeesData.getPercentMen())    done the trick